# replacement 60 amp breaker

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I’ve got a 60A breaker feeding a subpanel for a heat pump and water pump. I noticed that when the heat pump starts, there’s a buzzing from the panel & dimming of lights. I figured the breaker needed to be replaced, and I did, and that made the buzzing stop. However the breaker just doesn’t seem like it’s fully seated. I can’t quite get it to fully plug on in a satisfying way. I don’t understand why, since it seems like the same form factor as the old breaker and there are other double pole breakers of the same make in the panel.

Here’s a picture of the panel with the cover off. The new 60 amp breaker is the 7th switch from the top in the left column.
[image: breakers]

And here’s a picture of the panel info.
[image: panel]

Comment: picture would help

Comment: While you're in there, check the trip state on 6A.  It just looks out of place.

Comment: Yeah, this is a festival of varying breaker types. Don't forget GE, Challenger and Westinghouse! Seriously I would guess/hope that the white buttoned GFCI breakers are of the GFCB type.  But all the other breakers, if they're not on the approved list, replace em with Siemens QP. Breakers are cheap. Burning up a bus stab is expensive.  Note that Eaton CL type (not to be confused with BR type) is also allowed here because of a UL letter, however I yield to ThreePhaseEel's sense that the BR breakers are the lowest priority.

Comment: Probably I should just start a new question for this but…say I want to put in some Siemens afci breakers as replacements on some circuits. Where might I put the neutral pigtail?

Comment: @RobinDavis -- that's a new question, yes :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### You used the wrong breaker, so no wonder it's not wanting to fit

The 60A breaker you installed is a Square D HOMeline breaker (HOM260).  Unfortunately, that's the *wrong* breaker for a Crouse-Hinds panel that's designed and tested to accept Murray MP (now Siemens QP) and some Bryant/Westinghouse (now Eaton) breakers that don't really matter.  So, pull that HOM260 out pronto, take it back to wherever you got it from, return it, buy a Siemens Q260 instead, and install it in place of that bogus alien HOM260 you whacked in.

Comment: Isn’t that 50A breaker a few slots down the same type?

Comment: Yes, it is. All Square D HOM have to be replaced. There *may* be some other breakers that don't belong as well.

Comment: Care to speculate why that 50 amp breaker is so snug and the new 60 amp one isn’t?

Comment: Past damage from plugging in inappropriate breakers?

Comment: I also see Type BR in there which I don't think is a compliant cross for the old MP type, though it's mechanically quite close so might be 'fine' even though it's not 'right'.

Comment: @RobinDavis Someone may have "modified" the back plastic of the 50 amp breaker to make it fit better. You can pull it out and compare to your new "foreign" breaker.

Comment: Yeah, I'm less concerned about BR since the panel was tested with GFCB (BR GFCI) and QPGF though

Comment: @DoxyLover I’ll check. There are 3 of these breakers in the panel already.

Comment: Finally replaced it with the Siemens breaker. Seems better. I still haven’t pulled those other HOM breakers though.

Comment: @DoxyLover I pulled those other HOM breakers and they appear unmodified. Maybe they just fit.